# Get запрос Xamarin C#

Tags: c#, ios, get, xamarin.forms

Эмулятор айфона получает данные при `get` запросе, а физическое устройство нет, может кто то подскажет в чём может быть проблема?

```
public List<Photo> GetPhotoSearch(double northEastLatitude, double northEastLongtitude,
                                          double southWestLatitude, double southWestLongtitude)
        {
            List<Photo> photos = new List<Photo>();

            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create($"{totalUrl}/northEast='{northEastLatitude}'-'{northEastLongtitude}'" +
                                                   $"_southWest='{southWestLatitude}'-'{southWestLongtitude}'");
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    string line = "";
                    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        photos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Photo>>(line);
                    }
                }
            }
  
            response.Close();

            return photos;
        }
```

Comment: get запрос куда? Эмулятор иожет и в локалхост сможет попасть, а устройство в какой сети? Ошибка при запросе какая?

Comment: В настройках запращиваемых прав галку для работы с сетью поставили ?

Comment: Подсказка: [Как создать GET запрос](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26744471/12888024). Так же, `WebRequest` устарел, используйте [`HttpClient`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8#examples). И еще вот это почитайте - [Асинхронное программирование](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/async).

Comment: Покажите метод, откуда вызывается этот код? Из обработчика события кнопки? Покажите его. Приведенный код выглядит странно, но я не могу правильно его поправить, обратите внимание, что пока идет запрос к серверу, ваше приложение будет висеть. Это можно исправить, но мне надо видеть обработчик.

Comment: @tym32167 get запрос на сервер, ошибки при запросе нету, просто возвращается null, опять же, на эмуляторе всё работает корректно. Возможно такое что из-за плохого соединения не доходят данные и если возможно, то как с этим бороться? Благодарю за ответ.

Comment: @PavelPopov да, поставил, другие get запросы работают.

Comment: @aepot

Этот код вызывается из события.

вот как я вызываю метод
'photos = service.GetPhotoSearch(bounds.NorthEast.Latitude, bounds.NorthEast.Longitude, bounds.SouthWest.Latitude, bounds.SouthWest.Longitude);

Photos = new ObservableCollection<Photo>(photos);'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно у вас ошибка в URL запроса, так как вы не разделяете параметры с помощью `&` и не отделяете их от базового URL с помощью `?`.

Я дополнительно переписал все это под `HttpClient`, потому что Microsoft [не рекомендует](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) использовать устаревший `WebClient`.

```csharp
async void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    try
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> queryParams = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            { "northEast", $"'{bounds.NorthEast.Latitude}'-'{bounds.NorthEast.Longitude}'" },
            { "southWest", $"'{bounds.SouthWest.Latitude}'-'{bounds.SouthWest.Longitude}'" }
        };
        List<Photo> photos = await service.GetPhotoSearch(queryParams);
        Photos = new ObservableCollection<Photo>(photos);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

```csharp
private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

public async Task<List<Photo>> GetPhotoSearch(Dictionary<string, string> queryParams)
{
    string query;

    using (HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(queryParams))
    {
        query = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }

    using (var response = await client.GetAsync($"{totalUrl}/?{query}", HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
    {
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // бросает исключение, если сервер вернул ошибку
        string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Photo>>(json);
    }
}
```